# Lyapunov equation with semidefinite right-hand side

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, linear-control, lyapunov-functions

Consider the Lyapunov equation

$$A^TX+XA=-Q$$

with Hurwitz matrix $A$ and positive semi-definite matrix $Q\succeq0$.

When is its solution $X$ strictly positive definite?

Answer (score 5):

As is noted on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) about the Lyapnov equation, the (unique) solution to this equation can be written as
$$
X = \int_0^\infty e^{A^T\tau}Qe^{A\tau}\,d\tau.
$$
In all cases, this matrix will be positive semidefinite. The question remains as to when this matrix is strictly positive definite, i.e. when this matrix is also invertible.

> **Claim:** Given a Hurwitz $A$ and $Q \succeq 0$, $X = \int_0^\infty e^{A^T\tau}Qe^{A\tau}\,d\tau$ is invertible if and only if the observability matrix
> $$
> \mathcal C = \pmatrix{Q\\ QA\\ \vdots \\ QA^{n-1}}
> $$
> has full column-rank.

*Proof:*

$\implies$ (necessity of criterion): Suppose that $\mathcal C$ is not of full column rank. It follows that there exists a vector $v \neq 0$ such that $\mathcal Cv = 0$, which is to say that for $0 \leq k \leq n-1$, we have $QA^k v = 0$. By the Cayley Hamilton theorem, it follows that $QA^k v = 0$ for all $k \geq 0$. It follows that for all $t\geq 0$, we have
$$
Qe^{A \tau} v =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\tau^k}{k!}QA^kv = 0.
$$
It follows that
$$
Xv = \left(\int_0^\infty e^{A^T \tau}Qe^{A\tau} \,d\tau\right) v = 
\int_0^\infty e^{A^T \tau}\left(Qe^{A\tau}v\right)\,d\tau = 0
$$
Because $Xv = 0$, $X$ fails to be invertible. By contrapositive, if $X$ is invertible, then $\mathcal C$ must have full column rank.

$\Longleftarrow$ (sufficiency): see p. 21 of [these notes](http://maecourses.ucsd.edu/%7Emdeolive/mae280b/lecture/lecture1.pdf) for a proof.

Comment: The observability matrix is usually written with $C=Q^{\frac12}$ instead of $Q$. With that, the conjecture is correct. For sufficiency see e.g. [de Oliveira's notes, p.21](http://maecourses.ucsd.edu/~mdeolive/mae280b/lecture/lecture1.pdf).

Comment: @Conifold That’s a very nice find. I think that de Oliviera’s proof is nicer than what I eventually came up with (showing that the sum of the column spaces of $e^{\tau A^T}Q$ for all $\tau$ is $A^T$-invariant).