# Estimation for solution of the Lyapunov equation with semidefinite right-hand side

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, lyapunov-functions

Consider the Lyapunov equation
$$
A^TX+XA=−BB^T
$$
with Hurwitz matrix A.

We know, its solution $X$ be strictly positive definite if the pair $(B,A)$ is observable.

In this case, is it possible to obtain the lower estimation for $\lambda_\min(X)$ (like well-known
$\lambda_\min(X)\ge\frac{\lambda_\min(Q)}{2\|A\|}$ for $-Q\prec0$ in the right-hand side)?

Comment: It is probably helpful to readers on this site to know that this question is a followup to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4246927/81360).

Comment: It might be helpful to note that, due to the integral formula of the solution $X$, it is equivalent to find a lower bound to the integral 
$$
\int_0^\infty \|B^Te^{At}v\|^2\,dt
$$
where $v$ is a unit vector.

Comment: Another thought: I suspect that it is possible to get a lower bound in terms of the smallest singular value of the controllability matrix $\mathcal C(B,A)$.